# Why sulfur dissolved in ethylenediamine turns green?

Tags: color, amines

Davis, R. E., & Nakshbendi, H. F. (1962). Sulfur in Amine Solvents. Journal of the American Chemical Society, 84(11), 2085–2090. doi:10.1021/ja00870a017

I've also done this experiment. But what exactly forms and what really happens, I cannot find a recent text on the subject. Perhaps I'm searching the wrong terms?

Comment: Have you seen this? Spectroscopy of sulfur in ethylenediamine
Robert MacColl and Stanley Windwer J. Phys. Chem. 1970, 74, 6, 1261–1266.

Comment: And this one, Colored Sulfur Species in EPD-Solvents (Google the title, free access). Once you read these, you can perhaps write an answer. Interesting question. Recent paper does not necessarily mean the best or the most accurate version. Works from the 60-80s perhaps belong to the golden era, at least for spectroscopy and analytical chemistry in the USA.

Comment: two recent reviews on the topic: https://doi.org/10.1039/C3CS60119F and https://doi.org/10.1039/C8CS00826D

Comment: Very interesting question. I can't help but wonder if the green colour could be a combination of a large amount of weakly yellow neutral octasulfur plus a minute trace of the very strongly blue trisulfur radical monoanion.